# Contiuesly running input defined function

Tags: python

How can I make my code contiuesly running and keep asking for the user inputs and every time the input will be printed
Note: With while true I get the error EOFerror

```
 
 i = input()
 b = int(i,2)
    
 print (b)
```

Comment: Wrap the function body in a `while True` loop.  You should also read a Python tutorial.  This is about as basic as it gets.  There's no need to post for help on something as simple as a loop.

Comment: Maybe you need to be nice first, and then I editted my post, because I already tried the loop and didn't work

Comment: You will get EOFError if you type Ctrl-D while awaiting input

Comment: @FirasBayazed Well, of course you get eof if you don't provide input to the `input()` function.  You need to decide how you want to exit the loop.  Either provide some special string like `"quit"` to exit, or else catch the eof error and suppress it, exiting quietly.  You can do whatever you want once you learn the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can terminate your interactive input with Ctrl-D like this:

```
while True:
    try:
        n = input('Enter a binary number or Ctrl-D to end: ')
        x = int(n, 2)
        print(f'{n} = {x}')
    except EOFError:
        break
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: Thanks, and actually I just wanted to practice counting in binary from my smart phone, and all binary calculator apps doesn't accept zeros on the beginning, that's why I decided to write my own code, so thanks it's working⚘️

Answer (score 0):

You can put your block under loop as following:

```
while True:
  c()
```

or like that:

```
def c():
  while True:
    i = input()
    b = int(i, 2)
    print(b)
```